# print function doesn't execute outside a while cycle

Tags: python, control-flow

i have this function that works as intended except for the fact that the last print instruction outside the while cycle (print("why don't you print?")) never get executed and i don't understand why. after the break, the code execution should move forward.

```
def eval_cycle():
    done = 'done'
    last_expression = ' '
    while True:
        dato = eval(input('Insert an expression: '))
        if dato == done:
            print("Last expression is: ", last_expression)
            return dato
            break
        last_expression = dato
        print(dato)
    print("why don't you print?")
```

Comment: `return` returns *immediately*, before `break` can execute.

Comment: oh right, i'm so stupid :(

Answer (score 1):

When you `return` it immediately returns control flow out of the function.

Nothing in the function after that is executed.

As a sidenote, you may want to read the expression in as a string and then execute it. That way you can store it in `last_expression` rather than just the *result* of `eval`ing the expression.

Comment: you right, i didn't though about it. i'm stupid :(
anyway what do you mean "you may want to read the expression in as a string"?

Comment: You read the expression in as a string and then immediately `eval` it. As a result, you no longer have access to that input string: just the result of evaling it.

Comment: do you mean something like this? 

last_expression = 'nothing'
    while True:
        expression = input('Insert an expression: ')
        if expression == 'done':
            print('Last expression is: ', last_expression)
            return last_expression
            
        print(eval(expression))
        last_expression = eval(expression)